# Search/Query in a large table with many records

Tags: php, sql, search, phpmyadmin

I've created a html+php page wherein it searches in a mysql database. I am able to get output when my table contains a few records but when my table has over 100+ records it would no longer show records when i search and shows my else statement which is "0 records".

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!empty($sfname) || !empty($sgen) || !empty($sdoc) || !empty($smisc) || !empty($ssick) || !empty($sothers) ){

        $genQueryPart = !empty($sgen) ? "Gender LIKE '%$sgen%'" : "";
        $fnameQueryPart = !empty($sfname) ? "FullName LIKE '%$sfname%'" : "";
        $docQueryPart = !empty($sdoc) ? "Doctor LIKE '%$sdoc%'" : "";
        $miscQueryPart = !empty($smisc) ? "Misc LIKE '%$smisc%'" : "";
        $sickQueryPart = !empty($ssick) ? "Sickness LIKE '%$ssick%'" : "";
        $othersQueryPart = !empty($sothers) ? "Others LIKE '%$sothers%'" : "";

        $arr = array($genQueryPart, $fnameQueryPart,$docQueryPart,$miscQueryPart,$sickQueryPart,$othersQueryPart);

        $sql = "select * from index where ";

        $needsAnd = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i] != "") {
            if ($needsAnd) {
                $sql .= " AND ";
            }

            $needsAnd = true;
            $sql .= " " . $arr[$i];
        }

    }

//Get query on the database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_store_result();
    //Check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    //Headers
      echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
         echo "<th>File ID</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Full Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Gender</th>";
    echo "<th>Doctor</th>";
    echo "<th>Misc</th>";
    echo "<th>Sickness</th>";
    echo "<th>Others</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

  //output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['FileID']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['FullName']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['Gender']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['Doctor']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['Misc']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Sickness']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Others']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

        }
              echo "</table>";
    }
 else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

} else {
    echo "You must enter at least one value";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: How is this phpmyadmin related?

Comment: you should set `//Check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {` to `//Check results
    if (true)
    {` and see if any results are printed, if none are then your query is failing else where, if they are then you may need to store your result

Comment: Since im using phpmyadmin to handle my database, i was thinking there might be some setting need to be done when using tables with large values or something.. sorry I'm quite a beginner with this

Comment: @cmorrissey this is what you meant right? from if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) to  if ($result==true), ive tried this but it still doesn't show any values, just the 0 results again, what do you mean by "storing" my result?

Comment: Try inserting a `mysqli_store_result();` in a line after your `mysqli_query`. will fetch the whole resultset from the db, literally storing them before.

Comment: @DimasPante, could you look at my code now? i have placed the mysqli_store_result(); is that correct? I could still not output my correct result

Comment: Strange. You've tried echoing the `$sql` and pasting it into phpMyAdmin to see if returns anything?

Comment: @DimasPante Yes I tried echoing the contents of $sql and pasted it on phpmyadmin and i was able to get results

Comment: If you write the `mysqli_num_rows($result)` before, it shows anything on your file?

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition and paging to show more than 100 records after search. count the number of results after that use paging query to show records per page .This will be good idea for displaying large number of records.
Don't Merge Php and Html together . fetch the record in a function and use is to integrate in HTML

Comment: Could you show me how to do this? i mean like an exxample code